# Where to keep a GPG secret key for a Maven project in CI environment?

Tags: java, maven-2, continuous-integration, maven, gnupg

I'm trying to use [maven-gpg-plugin:sign](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html) in order to sign project artifacts before deployment to Sonatype OSS repository. The question is where shall I keep my secret key `secring.gpg`:

1. In continuous integration `~/.gnupg` directory
2. In project source code, e.g. `src/test/resources/gpg/secring.gpg`

And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If key is sensitive put it in ~/.gnupg directory on CI server and protect that directory with proper access modifiers.
2nd approach will allow every developer with access to project to see key.

Comment: Anyone with access to the CI server will be able to read the key through it.

Comment: With access to server and with access to ~/.gnupg, that is. But my answer was based on assumption that not every developer will have access to server and/or server's user under which CI is running.

Comment: anyone who can commit a unit test can get access to it (though in that case it might be obvious they did)

Comment: Not at all. Permission for a commit is not connected in any reasonable way to permission to have access to directory of user who runs CI server.

Comment: @VictorSorokin A malicious unit test can read the secret key, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessary -- perms on `~/.gnupg` may be restrictive enough to protect against this. It depends on CI server setup, really.