# How to configure Jenkins (Hudson) with gpg signature

Tags: maven, hudson, gnupg, jenkins

I'm in the process of transitioning to Maven (from Ant) and want to automatically sign my artifacts with a GPG in the Jenkins job.

From the documents that I've read, I need to manually run Maven to sign the documents

```
$ mvn clean deploy -Dgpg.passphrase=yourpassphrase
```

How do I do this without revealing the passphrase?

Is it possible?

I saw this SO question, but there's no indication of how to configure the Jenkins Job / Maven POM: [Where to keep a GPG secret key for a Maven project in CI environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511954/)

I have generated the GPG key on the same server that runs Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin
This one might also help if you need to deploy the keystore https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Secret+Plugin